# parse Json text to C# object in asp mvc 4

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a huge amount of customized attributes I want to save them in the DataBase, I was confused of how to store them in the database, i thought of storing them as a string separating them by

(`=` => name , value) (`;` => attribute , attribute) but the code wasn't elegant at all!

so i stat thinking of saving them as `Json` string but I couldn't found a 
`Json to object parser`

while we need only to call `json()` to parse `object to json string`

is there a better way than using json string  and  is there json string parser provided ?

Comment: Why don't you save them just one by one in an key/value table?

Comment: they are alot .. this approach is so ugly ... thanks sir!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Many people use [Json.net](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx) for serialization

```
var log  = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourObject>(logJson)
```

and the other direction

```
  var logJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(log);
```

Answer (score 24):

Try to use  `System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer`, here is example:

```
var yourObject = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<YourType>(strInput)
```

or

```
var yourObject = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize(strInput)
```

Comment: Awesome, no need of Json.net

Comment: Thanks, +1. FYI, this class is found in the System.Web.Extensions dll.

Comment: In, var yourObject = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize(strInput), Deserialize takes on more input parameter of type.. it does not work directly by specifying the string. !!

Answer (score 3):

You can use $.parseJSON, try this just for you to see the txt data:

```
var info = $.parseJSON(data);
 alert(info);
```

Comment: Thanks Sir, but what i want is server-side parsing ... thanks again.

Comment: use var js = JavaScriptSerializer.serialize(object), then use StringBuilder.append(js);

Comment: yep, i think that JavaScriptSerializer is my choice ! .. thanks

Comment: Ha! This is what I was looking for. +++++1