# MVC 4 Post on Nested JSON is null

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc

I'm currently working on a mobile app that communicates with an MVC4 API.
The problem I just noticed is that it seems to be unable to parse nested objects for some reason.

Example:

I'm POSTing the following data towards the url (http://localhost/DoSomething):

```
{
   "id":610,
   "dynamic":[
      {
         "fieldId":2756,
         "fieldValue":""
      },
      {
         "fieldId":2757,
         "fieldValue":""
      }
   ],
   "person":{
      "name":"test",
      "age":"123",
      "dateOfBirth":"test",
      "groups":[
         {
            "groupId":1182
         },
         {
            "groupId":1311
         },
         {
            "groupId":673
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Knowing that MVC will try to serialize it against the provided models, I have created the following model for the request:

```
    public class PersonRequest : RequestBase
    {
        public class Field
        {
            public int fieldId { get; set; }
            public string fieldValue { get; set; }
        }

        public class Group
        {
            public int groupId { get; set; }
        }

        public class Person
        {
            public string name { get; set; }
            public string age { get; set; }
            public string dateOfBirth { get; set; }
            public IEnumerable<Group> groups { get; set; }
        }

        public int id { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Field> dynamic { get; set; }
        public Person person { get; set; }
    }
```

In order to handle the input I have created the following route (which works):

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "PersonRequest",
                url: "DoSomething",
                defaults: new { controller = "Person", action = "Generate" }
            );
```

And my actual routing method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Generate(PersonRequest request)
{
    return Json(request, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

The response is however:

```
{"id":610,"person":null,"dynamic":null}
```

After searching for a possible solution, people said you would have to use IEnumerable for such situations instead of a List. Sadly, this didn't seem to be working for me.

---

Just some extra info:
I could always use JSON.stringify on the clientside on the dataobject person and dynamic, and eventually deserialize it myself on the backend (as shown in this topic: [parse Json text to C# object in asp mvc 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13489061/parse-json-text-to-c-sharp-object-in-asp-mvc-4)), but there has to be a better workaround for this problem.

---

Change: Changed groups to dynamic in the resulting json.

---

Solved: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29349804/2076351

Comment: How can you have `groups` key in your resulting JSON? Is it coming from `RequestBase` class?

Comment: The RequestBase contains a key "hash", which is all. Luckily, I have solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

Seems that my backend was properly setup. The fix was the way the data was sent towards the backend.

If you are sending a nested object towards the backend, to be parsed. You'll have to do two things:

1. Use JSON.stringify on the entire data send to the data
2. Use a proper content-type, e.g.:

   xhr.open("POST", url);

   xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");

   xhr.setRequestHeader("hash", params.hash);

   xhr.send(JSON.stringify(params.data));

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using IEnumerable<>, the query is fired at the end,
use List<> and check.

```
public class PersonRequest : RequestBase
    {
        public class Field
        {
            public int fieldId { get; set; }
            public string fieldValue { get; set; }
        }

        public class Group
        {
            public int groupId { get; set; }
        }

        public class Person
        {
            public string name { get; set; }
            public string age { get; set; }
            public string dateOfBirth { get; set; }
            public List<Group> groups { get; set; }
        }

        public int id { get; set; }
        public List<Field> dynamic { get; set; }
        public Person person { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: This was my first scenario which failed, luckily I've found the solution :) Check my other answer if you're curious.